# Why do I have a lot of root users in my Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I don't remember creating these users in my Mysql installation:

debian-sys-maint
phpmyadmin

And I have 3 Any users and 4 root users.

Here's the screen shot taken from Phpmyadmin:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltjJ1.jpg

And here's the command line version:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSflh.jpg

Should I be wary of these users? Or is this the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MySQL user is actually identified by a pair of username and hostname. `127.0.0.1`, `::1`, and `localhost` all allow you access from your local machine. Without them, you would not be able to connect. The only one that may be an issue is the `ip-10.242.75.6`, but I expect that is the machine's IP also?

As for the `phpmyadmin` and `ANY` users, the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage) says

> The USAGE privilege specifier stands for “no privileges.” It is used
>   at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as
>   resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing
>   account privileges.

Comment: Hello Dark, how can I secure my installation of Mysql? Should I remove the root ip-10.242.75.6?

Comment: Did you check to see if that is just the IP assigned to your machine?

Comment: My ip address is 112.200.xxx.xxx. How can I get the ip-xx.xxx.xx.x on my machine? What command should I enter?

Comment: If you don't know, I'd recommend that you not mess with the privileges. But to answer your question, `ifconfig` shows information about the network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You would have a record for each user and each IP address that user is allowed to connect from.

Answer (score 0):

These are permissions rather than separate user accounts. All it says is that, user `root` is allowed to connect from all those host addresses with `ALL_PRIVILEGES`. `localhost`, `::1` and `127.0.0.1` are the same machines address on which the SQL server is installed on.

Answer (score 0):

The listed hosts on the picture are different name variations of localhost. these 2 users should be able to access localhost by any of these names, that's why there are created duplicates